# How can I use a page's jQuery methods from a mozilla add-on?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to make this happen on a loaded page when a user clicks an add-on widget:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 405 }); 
$("input").trigger(e);
```

jQuery is already loaded in the target page. I've tried this:

```
var widgets = require("widget");
var tabs = require("tabs");
var pageMod = require("page-mod");

var widget = widgets.Widget({
    id: "button-test",
    label: "button-test",
    contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
    onClick: function() {
        tabs.activeTab.attach({
            contentScript:
                'var e = window.jQuery.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 405 }); $("input").trigger(e);'
        });
    }
});
```

I get the following error in the console:

```
Timestamp: 30/08/2012 14:06:36
Error: An exception occurred.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "javascript:var e = window.jQuery.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 405 }); $("input").trigger(e);", line 1, in 
TypeError: window.jQuery is undefined
```

Do I need postMessage or port.emit()? I;ve also tried just jQuery.event (without the window)

Comment: what error does javascript throw on your first codeblock?

Comment: I have pasted the only error I am getting. I can run the first codeblock fine in a console in Chrome

Comment: Not knowing anything about the space that a mozilla plugin loads in, can you access other global variables from window.XXX ? If you dont know, throw XXX = "found"; into your page code and alert(window.XXX); into your plugin - if that runs then you probably just need to wait for jQuery to load.

Answer (score 1):

> jQuery is already loaded in the target page.

Yes, and the webpage can access it. However, your content script [doesn't have direct access to the webpage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.9/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/accessing-the-dom.html), for security reasons. You *could* access jQuery (and other JavaScript variables defined by the page) as `unsafeWindow.jQuery` but this has serious security implications - not recommended to use. In your case it would be better to add your own copy of jQuery to your extension and load it with your content script - then you can be sure that jQuery is there and does exactly what you expect it to do:

```
var {data} = require("self");
tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.js"), data.url("contentScript.js")]
});
```

Comment: I have now done that. How do I use my own copy of jQuery to target events which occur on the target page?

Comment: @codecowboy: As long as they are regular DOM events there should be no issues... Then again, jQuery probably doesn't create regular DOM events meaning that you have to use [document.createEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent) directly.

Comment: unsafeWindow.jQuery is null. There also doesnt seem to be much point in adding my own copy of jquery as what I want to do is TRIGGER an event on the page itself (not listen for one). Sounds like I will have to do that in plain old JS.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
var widgets = require("widget");
var tabs = require("tabs");
var data = require("self").data;

var widget = widgets.Widget({
    id: "div-show",
    label: "Show divs",
    contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
    onClick: function() {
        tabs.activeTab.attach({
            contentScriptFile:
                [data.url("jquery-1.8.0.min.js")],
            contentScript: [
                "$(window).keydown(function(e){ \
                console.log(e.keyCode);}); $(window).trigger(jQuery.Event('keydown', { keyCode: 405 })) "]

        });
    }
});
```

Clicking on the widget icon generates a keydown event which then gets logged

Comment: Actually no it didnt. It does create the event. But does not target the loaded page.